# Creating a UI for a Python Program. Theming with ttk themes for tkinter but it doesn't work for labels and buttons and returns a strange error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Here is the code written so far... The code basically functions as a UI for another Python program. The other python program isn't causing any trouble...
No one has been able to assist me with the previous post so I rephrased and reposted...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import os
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = tk.ThemedTk()
app.get_themes()
app.set_theme("radiance")


app.geometry("400x400")
app.configure(bg='gray')


ex_activate_photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\bedga\PycharmProjects\GUIdev\ex_button_active.png") #It underlines PhotoImage
myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='normal')

ttk.Label(app, text='Ex', bg='gray', font=(
    'Verdana', 15)).pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)
app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\ex\ex_icon.ico')


def ex_activation():
    global pro
    print("Ex")
    pro = subprocess.Popen("python ex.py", shell=True)


def ex_stop():
    global pro
    print("Stopping Program... Please Wait!")
    os.kill(pro.pid, 0)


ex_activation_button = ttk.Button(app, bg='black', image=ex_activate_photo, width=120, height=120, command=ex_activation)


ex_stop_button = ttk.Button(app, bg='Gray', text='Stop Program', width=12, command=ex_stop, height=3)


ex_stop_button['font'] = myFont

app.title("Ex")
ex_activation_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ex_stop_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# app.mainloop()
while True:
    try:
        app.update()
        app.update_idletasks()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

The goal here is to ultimately theme every button (2) and the label at the top. I can then apply similar methods when theming new things in the future. Currently, the `PhotoImage` is not liking tk and ttk. The program underlines it. One of the buttons being themed is photo-based and the other is text. I have seen successful projects with themed image buttons.

This is the error I get with tk.photoimage

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ex/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    ex_activate_photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\ex\ex_button_active.png") #It underlines PhotoImage
AttributeError: module 'ttkthemes.themed_tk' has no attribute 'PhotoImage'
```

EDIT: This is the error I get for doing

```
import tkinter as tk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tkk
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import os
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ex/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    ex_activate_photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\ex\ex_button_active.png") #It underlines PhotoImage
  File "C:\Users\ex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\ex\PycharmProjects\ex\ex_button_active.png": no such file or directory
```

I didn't think ttk themes would have an issue with PhotoImage as  a variable because it is a theming library for tkinter.
I am very new the GUI development in Python and any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question as your earlier question (which you have deleted) again?

Comment: The first block of code, the first traceback, and the last traceback all seem to have different paths to the image file. Bottom line is, if python is saying it can't find a file, it can't find the file. You must have a typo in the filename or making some other assumption that is false.

Answer (score 2):

You are importing 2 libraries as `tk`, that's your main problem. First 3 lines of your code is here

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk
```

First and third lines have `as tk` so the latest one is taking over. The error message points to this as well. You should rename one of them.

Comment: There is an issue even if I do change the library name. This was something I forgot to mention. I updated the question with the errors I get with a modified importing of libraries.

Comment: That's a completely different problem though. My answer solves your original problem. Now you are moving the goalpost.

Also the example code you have and the error message you have contain totally different paths.